# change default settings in scangearmp used for canon MX926 scanner

Tags: drivers, xubuntu, settings, scanner, default

I installed scangearmp using the instructions from this website: `http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/12/canon-driver-scangear-mp-ubuntu-14-04/`. However I want to change the scan settings so, for example, I can just leave DPI set to 75 instead of the default of 300.

How do I change the default settings in scangearmp?

Details:

- Computer is Intel NUC - Intel Core i5-6260U @ 1.8GHzx4 Operating
  system - Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64 bit Local disk space > 200 GB
- Printer/scanner is Canon MX926 like this one: `https://www.canon.com.au/printers/pixma-mx926`. I can scan using the feeder (ADF) or the flat tray using the software.
- The software I installed is from the file named `scangearmp-mx920series-2.10-1-deb.tar.gz`
- After installing the software using the link above, I can just open Terminal and type `scangearmp` to open and use the program successfully.

The screenshot for the advanced interface is shown 
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkEuA.png). Note the Output resolution is what I mainly want to change from 300 to 75 dpi.

Also, when I swap between basic to advanced, the settings are reset to default.

How I can change and save these default settings and save a new set of default settings?

EDIT

In terminal, I successfully install xsane by typing `sudo apt install xsane`.
Then I type `xsane` to open the GUI and then a little window saying 'scanning for devices' pops up, then [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wl3br.png) window opens. For some reason, xsane doesn't want to work with the PIXMA MX926

Comment: so for your MX926 the SANE project provides good support: http://www.sane-project.org/sane-mfgs.html#Z-CANON and the simple GUI interface is SimpleScan; and the more sophisticated interface is xsane: so you have sane installed already; "sudo apt install xsane" and you can tweak it to your heart's content: read their help and support pages; so scangearmp is provided by Canon; it does not aim to be all things to all men/women; open-source sane should help you as an alternate

Comment: @pdc, would you know why xsane won't work with the MX926? If xsane works, and if I can then manipulate default settings, that would be the solution for me.. any help will be much appreciated thank you.